# Laravel 4: Order query relation randomly and limited

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 4 and I'm running into an issue with eloquent.

I've got it set up to grab the category, get the products and limit it to 2. However I'm having trouble getting the random element. I need it to select from two random products, rather than the newest/latest.

```
$products = Category::find($id)->products->take($limit);
$products->load('imageThumb');
return $products;
```

I'd like to keep the solution eloquent based, but if that's not an option I'll switch to a raw query code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$products = Category::find($id)->products()->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->take($limit)->get();
```

(sorry forgot the ->get() in my original answer)

Comment: I tried that at first, but it killed the ->load('imageThumb') function. I assume because it then returns the Category and not the products in the object?

Comment: I was wrong... I forgot the ->get();  I didn't realize that ->load was a collection method

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks so much, I'll be using it in a lot of places!

Answer (score 0):

How's big is the table?  If it is not too big you can use MySQL ORDER BY RAND()
http://davidwalsh.name/mysql-random

Eloquent something like:

```
->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))
```